# Can I use the typing information from another function as the return type in Python?

Tags: python, python-typing

In the following example, how can I properly annotate the return type of the `sum_two` function?

```py
from typing import Any, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')
S = TypeVar('S')

def sum_two(first: T, second: S):
    return first + second
```

Assuming the `__add__` operator is properly annotated for all possible arguments that will be passed to this function, is there some way to express the return type as the return type of calling `__add__` on objects of type `T` and `S`?

I would like to avoid using typing's `overload` decorator to identify all possible cases as there could be dozens of cases.

Comment: Using `typing.get_type_hints(func)['return']` *should* work. In fact, you can use it, Python runs it just fine, and adds the correct annotation, as can be verified by looking at the annotation of your `sum_two` function (actually not that, since `__add__` itself has no type annotation). But unfortunately `mypy` complains about “Invalid type comment or annotation”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can theoretically accomplish a part of his by making `first` a generic protocol, which lets you "capture" the return type of `__add__`. For example:

```
# If you are using Python 3.7 or earlier, you'll need to pip-install
# the typing_extensions module and import Protocol from there.
from typing import TypeVar, Protocol, Generic

TOther = TypeVar('TOther', contravariant=True)
TSum = TypeVar('TSum', covariant=True)

class SupportsAdd(Protocol, Generic[TOther, TSum]):
    def __add__(self, other: TOther) -> TSum: ...
```

Then, you could do the following:

```
S = TypeVar('S')
R = TypeVar('R')

# Due to how we defined the protocol, R will correspond to the
# return type of `__add__`.
def sum_two(first: SupportsAdd[S, R], second: S) -> R:
    return first + second

# Type checks
reveal_type(sum_two("foo", "bar"))  # Revealed type is str
reveal_type(sum_two(1, 2))          # Revealed type is int
reveal_type(sum_two(1.0, 2))        # Revealed type is float

# Does not type check, since float's __radd__ is ignored
sum_two(1, 2.0)

class Custom:
    def __add__(self, x: int) -> int:
        return x

# Type checks
reveal_type(sum_two(Custom(), 3))  # Revealed type is int

# Does not type check
reveal_type(sum_two(Custom(), "bad"))
```

This approach does have a few limitations, however:

1. It does not handle cases where there's no matching `__add__` in 'first' but do have a matching `__radd__` in 'second'.
2. You might get some weird results if you modify Custom so `__add__` is an overload. I think at least mypy currently has a bug where it doesn't know how to handle complicated cases involving subtypes and overloads properly.